# Submit multiple numbers in text area to insert into SQL Server table

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to do the following but cannot find a means to do so.

I am use HTML and PHP.

I have a list of numbers in such listing/format:

```
4443457
2554566
2347821
8978576
```

I would like to be able to copy these numbers exactly from the list above as they are written and paste them into maybe a text box or text area field.

Then upon pressing SUBMIT, those numbers are individually placed into a query/queries through php such as:

```
insert into table (column1, column2) values  ('test', '4443457')
insert into table (column1, column2) values  ('test', '2554566')
insert into table (column1, column2) values  ('test', '2347821')
insert into table (column1, column2) values  ('test', '8978576')
```

All in one submission step

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're here to help, not do your job for you. Show that you've at least attempted to do this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(explode("\n", $_POST['numbers']) as $value) {

    // insert $value
}
```

Comment: The amount of actual numbers is undefined:

Answer (score 0):

To get the numbers:

```
$numbers = explode("\n", $_GET['textarea']);
```

To insert in one query (it's faster):

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (14864, "a"), (64866, "b"), (564168, "c)
```

Comment: If you know how many values you'll be working with you can code up the insert query in one line, if not you can just use a for or foreach loop and string concatenation to generate the query programmatically.

Comment: The number of actual numbers is undefined...For example, one time I might have 3 to insert [eg 6958658, 98565478, 47851254] and the next time i might have 4 to insert [eg 52145236, 25412563, 12514874, 69584712]

Comment: You can build the query-string with the implode function.